# Why doesn't the Chinese remainder theorem contradict the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I am finding a contradiction between those two theorems and I do not know what I am doing wrong. First theorem is:

> The group $\Bbb Z_{m_1} \times \Bbb Z_{m_2} \times \dotsm \times \Bbb Z_{m_n}$ is cyclic and isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{m_1 m_2 \dotsm m_n}$ if and only if any of $m_i$'s are relatively prime.

And the second theorem is the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups, which says:

> Every finitely generated abelian group $G$ is isomorphic to a direct product of cyclic groups of the form $\Bbb Z_{p_1^{k_1}} \times \Bbb Z_{p_2^{k_2}} \times \dotsm \times \Bbb Z_{p_n^{k_n}}$ where $p_i$'s are not necessarily distinct primes.

For example, by the second theorem, we have $\Bbb Z_{360}$ is isomorphic to  $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z_5$, but by the first theorem, it should not be, since $2$ and $2$ are not relatively prime. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: *Note*: e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group (and hence a finitely generate abelian group), and does not occur in your version of the Fundamental Theorem.  It is, however, correct if you restrict to *finite* (as opposed to finitely generated) abelian groups.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups does not say that you can split up $360$ in any way you want as a product of primes and obtain an isomorphism. It says that for any abelian group of order $360$, there is a way to write $360$ as a product of prime powers $360=p_1^{r_1}\cdot\cdots \cdot p_n^{r_n}$ such that $G\cong \mathbb Z_{p_1^{r_1}}\times Z_{p_n^{r_n}}$.

Comment: Then, isn't the only way to do this is to use 1st theorem? Then we can deduce the same thing from theorem 1, why do we need theorem 2? I don't get it

Comment: Theorem 1 gives you a condition under which a product of groups of the form $\mathbb Z_{p_n^{r_n}}$ is isomorphic to a cyclic group. But not all finite abelian groups are cyclic (if they were, then you won't need theorem 2). Theorem 2 tells you something in the other direction. It says that any finite abelian group is a product of group of the form $\mathbb Z_{p_n^{r_n}}$, but not necessarily with the condition on the primes that is stated in theorem 1.

Answer (score 3):

The first theorem gives you that if a group is *cyclic*, it may be factored into a direct product of cyclic groups of relatively prime order, whereas the second theorem gives you that if a finite group is *abelian*, it is isomorphic to *some* direct product of cyclic groups.  $\mathbb{Z}_{360}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_5$, but it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_8\times \times \mathbb{Z}_9\times\mathbb{Z}_5$.  You can factor out relatively prime numbers, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}\cong\mathbb{Z}_p\mathbb{Z}_q$ when $p\not= q$ and $p,q$ are prime, but you can't decompose numbers which aren't relatively prime, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}_8\not\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Answer (score 2):

You are misinterpreting the 2nd theorem. ${\bf Z}_{360}$ is isomorphic to ${\bf Z}_8\times{\bf Z}_9\times{\bf Z}_5$. Note that, for example, ${\bf Z}_4$ is not isomorphic to ${\bf Z}_2\times{\bf Z}_2$.

Comment: To put it another way, $\mathbb Z_4 \cong \mathbb Z_{2^2} \not\cong \mathbb Z_2^2$ :)